# Using array_map when importing data from xlsx

Tags: php, arrays, escaping, xlsx, xls

I am importing some data into a mysql table from an xls file.

On the data, i want to use the mysqli_real_escape_string function, before i insert it into the sql table.

My question is that: where should i put the array_map with the escape function in this code below?

Thanks for help.

```
    if(isset($_POST['submitButton']))
{
    if($_FILES['file']['size'] != 0 )
    {
        if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 5242880 ) { $error[] = "A fájl mérete maximum 5 MB lehet."; }
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(!array_key_exists($ext, $fajl_types)) { $error[] = "Nem engedélyezett fájl típus."; }

        if(count($error) == 0 )
        {
            $path = "../imports/" . date( "Y-m-d" ) . '-' . rand(1, 9999) . '-' . $_FILES['file']['name'];
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path ))
            {
                $file_name = basename($path);
                $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('../imports/'.$file_name);
                $dataArr = array();
                foreach($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
                    $worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getTitle();
                    $highestRow         = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
                    $highestColumn      = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'
                    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);

                    for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {
                        for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) {
                            $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
                            $val = $cell->getValue();
                            $dataArr[$row][$col] = $val;
                        }
                    }
                }
                unset($dataArr[1]); // since in our example the first row is the header and not the actual data

                $user_pass = "";
                $user_reg_date = date("Y-m-d-H:i:s");
                $user_last_login = "";
                $user_aktivation = "";
                $user_vevocsoport = (int)0;
                $user_newpass = "";
                $user_imported = (int)1;

                foreach($dataArr as $val) 
                {

                    $sql = "INSERT INTO user 
                    (
                        user_vnev,
                        user_knev
                    )
                    VALUES
                    (
                        '".$val['0']."',
                        '".$val['1']."'
                    )";
                    $import = mysqli_query($kapcs, $sql) or die("IMPORT-ERROR - " . mysqli_error($kapcs));
                    $ok = 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $error[] = "A fájl feltöltése nem sikerült.";
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $error[] = "Nem választott ki fájlt.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Just do it in the query

Answer (score 0):

You can add it when building the query. Like this, the escaping and building the query, which are both related to each other, are close to each other in your code.

```
foreach($dataArr as $val)
{
    $escapedVals = array_map(function($value) use ($kapcs) {
        return mysqli_real_escape_string($kapcs, $value);
    }, array_slice($val, 0, 2));
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO user 
        (
            user_vnev,
            user_knev
        )
        VALUES
        (
        "' . implode ('","', $escapedVals) . '"
        )';
    $import = mysqli_query($kapcs, $sql) or die("IMPORT-ERROR - " . mysqli_error($kapcs));
    $ok = 1;
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you, i will try it soon. But how can i test it? What should i write into each excel column?

Comment: @KissTom87 I did not change any of your logic, i just added the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to a possible place. You should be able to use whatever sheet you have used before.